# Merging 2 SQLite databases, in pandas chunking or in SQLite? Or in Dask?

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, merge, dask

I am new to this website and this is my first question so apologies in advance if its trivial or I am being stupid:

My issue is that I have two datasets, currently stored in 2 sqlite database files. The first (db1) has approx 30million rows x 8 columns (18gb) , the second (db2) is 20k rows x 9 columns. They have one column in common which is subject_id.

In a perfect world I would be able to load each complete db into a pandas dataframe and then perform merge as per below and then perform my data analysis on the resultant merged dataframe:

pd.merge(df_db1, df_db2, on='subject_id')

What I want to achieve is for each row in db1 where subject_id matches with a subject_id in db2, I want all the columns of db2 to be added to the end of the db1 row. This will mean where db1 has a matching subject_id to db2 it will have a further 8 columns of data appended, and where it does not have a matching subject_id, these 8 appended columns will remain blank.

I hope this makes sense.

My current lines of inquiry are, even though my sqlite browser almost crashes every time I load up db1 due to its size, can i perform the required operation all within sql with an ATTACH and then merge equivalent command ? If so, what is the best way to do this please?

If this is not possible or efficient, would it be best to do everything in python and pandas, and then populate a new 'merged' database.  IE load all of db2 into a pandas dataframe, and then pd.read_sql db1 in 1million row chunks, in pandas, perform the merge, then send this new merged dataframe piece by piece upto the new 'merged' database ?

I was looking into dask as this looks to be what I am after given the limited (8gb ram) memory I am working with, however I dont think a dask dd.pd.read_sql exists as yet.

Many thanks in advance for any time spent looking at this. I have spent the last week tearing hair out as cannot workout how to merge these 2 data sets in this way.

Comment: I would copy the small table into the larger sqlite database and then use sqlite to do the join

Comment: Wow that was quick, thanks for your response. The small table has different columns to big table so I had thought this wouldn't be possible. However I think if I understand correctly I should populate another table in db1, and then from here perform the join within SQLite? If so, thanks for the pointer here. Would you be able to help with the SQL I would need to execute to make this join?

Comment: @MRocklin Amazing. Got it all working. Apologies for being lazy asking for the SQL, as demonstrated in my original post, I am an SQLite newbie.. Your one sentence was exactly what was required. Have a great evening and thanks again for the pointer.